# How to hide error messages automaticly in libnotify in gnome shell?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-3, gnome-shell, libnotify

Im using ubuntu 11.10 and gnome-shell 3. I`m using Guard to notify test pass or failure.

When I have green test notification hide automatically after few seconds but When my test have errors I have to click on error messages to hide because they are overlay all other notifications.

How to setup autohide for errors??

[image]

Comment: I think you need to give some more context for this question.

Comment: Ok, i write this more clearly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Arch Linux. The following worked for me:

Add on Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'libnotify'
end
```

Add on guard file, inside "guard :tests do":

```
 notification :libnotify, :timeout => 1, :transient => true, :append => false, :urgency => :low
```

run bundle install again, restart guard, and it works.

Perhaps gnome 3.4 don't hide critical notifications.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by fotanus :urgency seems to be the key, but note that this was only exposed in guard 1.0.2 released April 30, 2012 so you will need at least this version.